# Cannot import name promolglobals

Tags: python, pymol

I am trying to utilize the plugin 'ProMol' on my compiled, open-source version of PyMol. When PyMol loads, I get the error "Unable to initialize plugin 'ProMol' (pmg_tk.startup.ProMol)". When I go to the plugin menu and select load ProMol, I get the error message "cannot import name promolglobals".

I have saved the ProMol plugin files from sourceforge in the pmg_tk\startup folder, and am able to use other plugins that this package came with. Promolglobals.py is saved in pmg_tk\startup\ProMol.

This is the link to the ProMol files: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sbevsl/files/ProMOL/ProMOL-5/

*There is no support link for this file listed in sourceforge.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue, or is it an actual problem with the file? If there are any troubleshooting methods I can take, please let me know. I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: Did you also try using the exe installer for Windows? Perhaps this might help.
Are you sure about the capitalization of your file names?
pmg_tk\startup is it in the python2.7 folder or in the pymol folder? The manual is a bit ambiguous about it. My guess would be that the pymol folder is correct one.

Comment: I used the exe installer for windows. I did not change any file names. I have it installed in pmg_tk\startup in python2.7 alongside ADpugin (for autodock, which works fine). I have pymol installed in python2.7 as a site package and there is no pmg_tk\startup folder. (I have also installed promol on puchased versions on pymol in its own pmg_tk\startup, but this has not worked either.)

Comment: I'd ask the authors for help or try it in on Linux.